# How do I make a dictionary of zeroes in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Say I've got a (long) list of keys:

```
`a`b`c
```

How do I make a dictionary where every value is zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your list is saved as a variable, this can be achieved with the `count` keyword. For example

```
q)c:`a`b`c
q)c!(count c)#0
a| 0
b| 0
c| 0
```

will return your dictionary of zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a blank (or existing) dictionary you can assign 0 to all of your keys:

```
q)c:`a`b`c
q)d:()!()
q)d[c]:0
q)d
a| 0
b| 0
c| 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one more option, can also use each-right `\:` with assign `:` to do this:

```
q)(`a`b`c!()):\:0
a| 0
b| 0
c| 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If 0 is a default value, you could also use fill when indexing into it:

```
q)d:`a`b`c!til 3
q)d[`d]
0N
q)0^d[`d]
0
```